# What does it mean to be a "family of parametrizations?"

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading this book and there is a definition of a curve as follows: [image]

> So, according to the authors what is a curve?

(I am getting confused by "family of all parametrizations" part of the text. (I am guessing, a smooth curve is $\{z([a,b]) |  z(t):[a,b]\to \mathbb{C},z,z'\text{are continuous}\}$ but I am not sure.)

> Also, what do they mean by opposite orientation?

Comment: The opposite orientation would mean starting at $b$ and going to $a$,  i.e. changing the direction we follow the curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
Thanks to help and suggestions by other users on chat, I tried to define a smooth curve $\gamma$ by the following:

Definition: Define a relation $\sim$ on the set of all smooth parametrizations and we write $z \sim w$ if $z$ and $w$ are equivalent.

$\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set of all smooth parametrizations(though this needs proof).

So, $\gamma$ is a curve from $w_1$ to $w_2$ and $\gamma:=\{[z]|\text{z is a smooth paramaterization}, z(a)=w_1, z(b)=w_2\}
$